# JAVA: How can I initialize an ArrayList to specific class type with Object-wrapped instance?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Let's say we have 2 `class` types below:

```
class Cola {}
class Milk {}
```

And an `Object` instance which type is one of above classes:

```
public Object getDrink(boolean random){
    if(random)
        return new Cola();
    else
        return new Milk();
}
Object drink = getDrink(random);
```

Of course I can check the class of `drink` by calling `drink.getClass()` or `drink.getClass().getCanonicalName()` or so. That's ok.

My problem is that, I want to make and initialize an ArrayList of `drink` class type, NOT `Object` type.

```
ArrayList<Object> list   // This is NOT what I want.
ArrayList<drink.getClass()> list2   // Exactly what I want (but not right)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface called `Drink`

In both `Cola` and `Milk` implement the interface `Drink`

Store as `ArrayList <Drink> list;`

Comment: Thanks! This is not the best solution in my situation, but I think I caught a huge hint :D

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Drink` interface, modify `Cola` and `Milk` to `implements Drink` and then you can use a `List<Drink> list2`.